# Cisco Anyconnect on Windows 8.1 x64 machine

Tags: windows-8.1, cisco-vpn-client

I cannot get Cisco Anyconnect VPN to run on any of my Windows 8.1 x64 machines.  The message is not very helpful.  There is also an error in the Event Viewer with source "WebVPN" and details

```
Relay:1616 
failed to connect to destination: 404
verify destination address, DNS and webtype ACL settings at the VPN device
```

You may also see this warning in the event log:

> The application (Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client, from vendor Cisco) has
>   the following problem: To function properly, Cisco AnyConnect VPN
>   Client must be reinstalled after you upgrade Windows.

Which is misleading.  Any ideas? A screen shot of the error is below.

[image: Screen with error message]

Answer (score 3):

For Windows 8.1 you need to fix a registry entry:

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\vpnva

The value in the DisplayName setting comes with garbage in it.

> @oem31.inf,%vpnva_Desc%;Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client
>   Virtual Miniport Adapter for Windows x64

Remove all the stuff up to the point that it says "Cisco AnyConnect…".  With no more special characters to mess things up the service will now run  fine.